# Why does “revocable” have first-syllable stress?

Tags: pronunciation, stress

Read the following “canonical” sets of related words, and notice the (uncontroversial) stress patterns:

- Renew, renewable, renewably
- Regret, regrettable, regrettably
- Repeat, repeatable, repeatably

(They all keep the second-syllable stress throughout)

Now, consider the “outlier” set:

- Revoke, revocable, revocably

**Why** does the stress move from the second to the first syllable (according to most sources)? To me, neither first- nor second-syllable sounds weird. This is in contrast to the canonical sets.

My **hypothesis** for the outlier is the existence of the word “revocation”, which has first-syllable stress. However, a **counterexample** set exists:

- Combine, combinable, (combinably)

The first-syllable-stressed "combination" exists, but that doesn't make us change the stress of "combinable".

Comment: It's not the only word that behaves like this: *refute, refutable; repair, reparable.*

Comment: @PeterShor I've always heard (and said) "refutable" as reh-FYOOT-a-bull (and [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refutable) agrees), but repute/reputable is a good pair.

Comment: @Hellion I agree. (Also note that the noun exists for all three words: refutation, reparation, reputation)

Comment: Also compare and comparable (COMP-ruh-bul)

Comment: @Mitch, I'd pronounce comparable as (com-PARA-bul).

Comment: @Steve Yes, that's a common alternate pronunciation of 'comparable'.[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comparable) and [Cambridge]( https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/comparable), give the pronunciation with stress on the first syllable as the standard. I think it is becoming more common to stress the second syllable nowadays.

Comment: I pronounce comparable both ways depending on context. COMP-ra-ble generally to indicate that two things are sufficiently similar to allow for comparison by some metric; but com-PAR-a-ble as a technical term in computer science to indicate that a data type implements a method for comparison, for example the `Comparable` interface in Java to me is always com-PAR-a-ble, not COMP-ra-ble.

Comment: I'm an American English user and pronounce revocable with the accent on the _second_ syllable, VOC, like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQMWoXHxN6I).  That is the pronunciation I would expect from others.  The accent on the first syllable, REV, like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WEu5HC_2xas), sounds 'foreign', perhaps British.  I would _not_ expect that pronunciation except as part of the antonym irrevocable.

Comment: I wonder if part of the reason is influence from antonyms like "irrevocable" and "incomparable." Both of those words are pretty common, whereas the words "irrenewable," "irregrettable," and "irrepeatable" are pretty much nonexistent. (I have heard _irrepetible_ in Spanish, though.)

Comment: @Kirt As a Brit, I would also put the stress on the second syllable, not the first. The stress on the first syllable sounds alien. (Interestingly, my brother would also pronounce it with the stress on the second syllable, while my father pronounces it with the stress on the first)

Comment: In agreement that I feel a tendency to accent the second syllable of revocable, with a long "o". But to me, either pronunciation is acceptable and sounds fine. This is supported by at least some dictionaries.

Comment: @Kirt: Why would "irrevocable" have a stress on "re"?? I pronounce it as "ir-re-VO-ca-ble" as well, just like "ir-re-PLA-cea-ble".

Comment: @user21820 It would not have the stress on "re" but rather on "rev".  Ir-REV-oc-able, a bit like irreconcilable but without the hard stress on CI.

Comment: Well, I think @AndrewRay's example demonstrates that strange pronunciations come from rote-memorization and not from logical derivation or even euphony (which is why it sounds strange). If you teach a child the word "compare" and various words ending with "able" but never let the child hear someone pronounce "comparable", you will get "com-PA-ra-ble" when you ask the child to form that adjective. I can bet the same will happen with "revocable" and "irrevocable".

Comment: @Kirt wait, are you suggesting to pronounce irreconcilable as ir-REK-kun-si-li-ble?

Comment: @AndrewRay Suggesting?  I don't think it is my place to tell others how to pronounce a word.  But what I say, and usually what I hear in the US, is ir-REK (soft)-kun-SI (hard)-li-ble.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Words ending in *-able* follow multiple pronunciation patterns

This is part of the more general phenomenon that English has many pairs of affixes or word parts that mean the same thing but have different forms because of the history of the language.

For example, *un-* and *in-* mean just about the same thing, but different words form a negation using one, both, or neither for complicated reasons.

The "productive" pattern (the pattern that is most easily applicable to newly formed words) for *-able* is to have the same pronunciation, including stress, in the adjective as in the related verb. For example, *deˈgradable* as in *deˈgrade,* *exˈcludable* as in *exˈclude,* *reˈcyclable* as in *reˈcycle,* and so on. (In this answer, I follow the IPA convention of marking stress with the sign ˈ placed before the stressed syllable.)

But in addition to words that follow this productive pattern, there are a number of words that follow other patterns that developed in earlier time periods. I think the age of the word *revocable* is the most important factor that contributed to the pronunciation *ˈrevocable.*

#### Stress evolved between Middle English and the present day

*Revocable* is not a newly formed word. It dates back to Middle English (the Oxford English Dictionary's dates its first citation to around 1500, and has a couple more from the 16th century; the antonym *irrevocable* is attested even earlier).

The stress pattern of words derived from Latin and French changed between Middle English and present-day English. In Middle English, it seems that words borrowed from French often had stress in the same position that present-day English speakers tend to hear it in French: either on the final syllable of a word, or the second-to-last syllable in cases where the word ends in a silent/mute "e" (which at the start of the Middle English period was not silent, but was pronounced as an unstressed vowel sound, the schwa [ə]). So in this period, we would find *(ir)revocable* pronounced as something like [i(r)revoˈkaːblə], and likewise, other adjectives ending in *-able* that were borrowed in the Middle English period probably had pronunciations at this time where the primary stress fell on the *-a-* of the suffix.

Here's a pair of lines from the [prologue of the Canterbury Tales](https://chaucer.fas.harvard.edu/pages/general-prologue-0) (written sometime around or before 1400) that shows that both the first and second *a* in *charitable*, as well as the *ou* in *pitous*, functioned as stressed syllables in Chaucer's English:

> She was so charitable and so pitous
>
> She wolde wepe, if that she saugh a mous

(Harvard's Geoffrey Chaucer Website, Middle English text taken from Larry D. Benson., Gen. ed., *The Riverside Chaucer,* Houghton-Mifflin Company; with permission of the publisher.)
The meter is iambic pentameter: here is my transcription in IPA of what the reconstructed Middle-English pronunciation would be, with a stress marker before each syllable that is stressed by the meter (not differentiating between primary and secondary stress):

[ʃeː ˈwas sɔː ˈtʃariˈtaːbl and ˈsɔː piˈtuːs]

[ʃeː ˈwoldə ˈweːp if ˈðat ʃeː ˈsawx a ˈmuːs]

When words like *revocable* and *charitable* shifted their stress to an earlier syllable, the change may have proceeded in some cases by converting a former secondary stress into the new primary stress. In English, secondary stresses coming before the primary-stressed syllable tend to be placed on alternating syllables, like this: [i(r)**.ˌre**.vo.**ˈkaː**.blə]. So switching the position of the primary and secondary stresses would give us [i(r).ˈre.voˌkaː.blə]. In fact, in such cases the later, originally stressed syllable seems to have generally ended up becoming completely unstressed, with the vowel becoming short and reduced as a result, so by the time of present-day English we have [ɪˈrɛvəkəbl̩].

#### Analogy in modern English continues to affect stress patterns

The influence of other words, such as *revocation*, where the *re-* still has secondary stress to this day certainly may have supported the use of primary stress on the first syllable of *revocable.*

As mentioned in the comments, many old *-able* adjectives actually have, or have had, multiple pronunciations: one old one stressed on the second syllable before *-able* based on the historical stress-shifting process outlined above, and one newer one stressed on the first syllable before *-able* based on the modern productive rule (or on analogy with it: the position of stress has changed even in some adjectives like *deˈspicable* (older pronunciation *ˈdespicable*) and *forˈmidable* (older pronunciation *ˈformidable*) where there's no corresponding verbs **deˈspic* or **forˈmid* to serve as a base).

Comment: Thank you for your fascinating answer. Can you please explain how the stresses are derived from the lines in the Canterbury Tales? It doesn't seem like there's a consistent meter anyway?

Comment: @BenjaminWang: It is in iambic pentameter, so the second syllable and each alternate syllable from that is stressed. I added a transcription of what approximately the Middle English pronunciation would have been

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the transcription. Pronouncing the lines in current-day English would not have made sense metrically.

Comment: Also _lámentable_, which I still hear more often than _laméntable_ despite _lamént_. Off the top of my head, Phantom of the Opera (the Webber musical) has a rhyme that depends on it.

Comment: @Draconis do you mean in "Notes/Prima Donna": "Otherwise the chorus was entrancing, / But the dancing was a lamentable mess!"?

Comment: @BenjaminWang Yep, that's the one.